# Undefined variable: user

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

With this code i have an obviously

```
Undefined variable: user
```

So, my question is how can I access the `$user` in `add.ctp`? Probably this is basic but I am new in Cake. Or the correct way is call the method like:

```
$user = new UsersController();
$user -> add();
```

?

---

UsersController.php

```
    public function add() {
           ...   
           $user = $facebook->getUser();
           ...
    }
```

add.ctp

```
<?php if ($user){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $logoutUrl; ?>">Logout</a>
<?php }else{ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set it:

```
public function add() {
       ...   
       $user = $facebook->getUser();
       $this->set('user', $user);
       ...
}
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#interacting-with-views